# Caroussel / Slider jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, slider, carousel

Currently I'm creating a new website for a customer. The designer thought about some sort of slider / caroussel which I need to create using JavaScript. A similar slider / carousel which looks like the slider allmost exactly can be found here. See: http://www.akker.biz/public/aanbod.aspx  (click on a car and see the slider)

My question is, is there a jQuery plugin which I can use and is easy to install.

Thanks all for your help!

Greetings;

Comment: Nivo Slider is awesome. If you are using ASP.NET I have a custom server control which does all the javascript for you through Visual Studio IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://addyosmani.com/resources/coverflow/demo/demo.html

The demo looks alot like the one you provided. Coverflow-ish

Comment: Hi, thank you all for the tips. I used this one and worked fine. The effect is not 100% similar, but good enough :) I also added a shadowbox for a nice view of all the images.

Answer (score 1):

[Nivo Slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/) is pretty cool, and easy to use.

Or you can use [JCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/) is closer to what you need

Comment: Yup Nivo Slider is awesome - I also took the time to create a custom server control for asp.net that makes it easy as 1,2,3 to add to page (with every config option available also)

Answer (score 0):

http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/ has a ton of options. It's heavy though. jCarouselLite is an alternative if you only need a few options. The one you presented is very simple.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/jquery-image-galleries-sliders-best-of/

That's a nice collection of 3d image galleries which you can download and use yourself quite easily